# Firebase messaging with Firebase hosting does not get initialized properly

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase hosting to serve a web application. Firebase usually initializes correctly when using the automated initialization.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Some stuff -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Some stuff -->
  </body>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <script>
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
      // Works fine
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      // Works fine
     });
</html>
```

So in the above minimal example I can use auth and storage but adding a call to messaging fails.

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

The associated error message is:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: Missing App configuration value: "appId" (messaging/missing-app-config-values).

I understand the error message but the weird part to me is that usually Firebase SDKs are initialized correctly when using Firebase Hosting and calling `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>`. This seems not to be the case here for the Firebase messaging SDK. When I am leaving out this call and initialize the Firebase application myself with `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`, the Firebase messaging SDK gets initialized correctly and I can use it.

I would like to avoid initializing the Firebase application myself as I think Firebase hosting should take care of it. Is there any step I am missing which is specific for using the Firebase messaging SDK? I could not find any following https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client.

Comment: You'll want to compare the contents of `/__/firebase/init.js` with your own `firebaseConfig`, but most likely the former is missing a value like `messagingSenderId`. If that's indeed the case, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they know whether that's intentional or it may be a bug.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think they just didn't add their web app to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the conents of `/__/firebase/init.js` doesn't contain all of the messaging information until you actually go through the process of [adding a web app to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), particularly step 2.  It's not enough to just deploy the code to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: I actually did that. It seems like ```/__/firebase/init.js``` is missing ```appId``` when running on localhost. I just deployed and called my web application through the url provided by Firebase hosting and there the appId is included. Looks like I need to distinguish between where the web application is running.